# Possible to use "INSERT INTO @VARIABLE EXEC() AT LINKED_SERVER" syntax? (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I am trying to execute a query on a linked server, but I need the results locally.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
(
greeting CHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @test
EXEC('select ''hello'' as greeting')

SELECT * FROM @test
```

Uses an `EXEC()` and `INSERT INTO` but, obviously the query is executing locally.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
(
greeting CHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @test
EXEC('select ''hello'' as greeting') AT LINKED_SERVER

SELECT * FROM @test
```

Does not work at all.

`SELECT greeting FROM OpenQuery(LINKED_SERVER,'SELECT''hello'' AS greeting')`

Accomplishes exactly what I want, but I need to be using a dynamic string, and the only way to make that work is to make my entire query a huge string and put it into an EXEC(), which I don't want to do since it is really ugly....

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your middle version works for me in a simple test case. What is the exact problem you're experiencing with it?

Comment: It says that a distributed transaction isn't supported by the server.  I probably should mention that the linked server isn't another SQL Server but an OLE DB.

Comment: But it is good to know, at least that what I am trying to do probably just isn't possible with an OLE db since the syntax is valid.

Comment: @user468341: That is a horse of a different color then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
INSERT INTO @test
EXEC('select TOP 1 ''hello'' as greeting FROM LINKED_SERVER.SomeDB.dbo.SysObjects')
```

And assuming you don't want to actually just get the word "hello"... you *probably* want to do something like actually selecting a value from a table, then the above should be even more likely what you want.